# Is an interrogative sentence like "So did you?" or "So is she?", possible?

Tags: sentence-structure, questions, responses

> A: Mike came here yesterday.
>   B: Possible responses: (1) Did you, too? (2) So did you?

Instead of saying, "Did you come here yesterday, too?", can you say, (1) "Did you, too?" and (2) "So did you?"?

Are (1) and (2) both OK?
If (2) is not OK, could you tell me why?

How about this situation?: Jane has two daughters, Grace and Emily.
When Jane shows you a photo of Grace and you, knowing that she has two daughters, say, (3)"Grace is beautiful.", can you add to it, "So is she (Emily)?", meaning, (4)"Is Emily beautiful, too?"

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of saying, "Did you come here yesterday, too?", can you say, (1) "Did you, too?" and (2) "So did you?"?

The simple answer: you can say (1), but you can't say (2).

It is true that the word "so" can mean "also". (For example, if someone says "I saw a penguin yesterday", you can say "So did I!", meaning "I did, also!") But (with a caveat) the word "so" *can't* mean "also" in a question like (2).

I don't know how to explain *why* you can't use "so" in that way. I think it's because the word "so", when used to mean "also", has to be at the beginning of the sentence or clause, but in a question similar to "Did you, too?", the head verb ("did", in this case) has to be at the beginning of the question. These two requirements contradict each other.

The question "So did you?" *does* make sense in a different context. For example:

> "Jason said that I should go to that German restaurant."
>
> "So did you?"
>
> "Yes, I went there, and the food was delicious!"

But in the above question, "so" doesn't mean "also"; it means something like "consequently". (Also, the stress in the above question is on the word "did".)

Now, when I said that the word "so" can't mean "also" in a question like (2), I said that there was a caveat.

The caveat is: *any* sentence can be made into a question without changing the word order, as long as your intention is to ask for *confirmation*. In other words, you *can* ask "So did you?", but only if you think that the answer is yes. In this usage, the question "So did you?" is equivalent to "You did, too?", not to "Did you, too?" Also, in this usage, the stress is on the word "you".

Answer (score 0):

1) is definitely okay and understandable.

2) can be used as well, provided that - if spoken - you put the accent on *you*. For example:

> - Everyone went crazy, they took of all their clothes and started dancing!
>
> - So, did *you*?
>
> - God, no! I'd never do such a thing!

It puts more focus on the person you're speaking to and communicates that you're not really interested in what others did, while *did you, too?* doesn't have as much of that emphasis.

Comment: Thank you, Maciej.
Is that comma indispensable?

Comment: No it isn't. Here, "so" is merely used for emphasis. It does *not* mean 'also'.